# If file is in previous directory remove other directory with the same name of file without extension

Tags: bash, shell, unix, for-loop

I have a problem. I have files with extension .war in /root/tmp/despliegue/webapps, I want remove directories with the same name without extension in /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps

I have obteined the names without suffix with:

```
for entry in /root/tmp/despliegue/webapps/* ; do basename $entry .war ; done
```

I need remove with the output previous loop... someone like this.

```
for entry in /root/tmp/despligue/webapps/* ; do rm -rf /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps`basename $entry  .war`; done
```

Thank you guys.

Sorry for my very bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to loop over files that have the .war extension, so you should use `*.war` instead of `*`:

```bsh
for entry in /root/tmp/despligue/webapps/*.war; do 
   rm -rf "/usr/share/tomcat6/$(basename "$entry" .war)"
done
```

Your question says that you have the .war files in `/root/tmp/despliegue/`, but your code says they are stored in `/root/tmp/despliegue/webapps/`. Also the questions says the directories are in `/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/`, however your code uses `/usr/share/tomcat6/`.

Comment: Might work in this case, but I would be very hesitant to do `rm -rf` in a script without any error checking that what I'm deleting is actually what I want to delete.

Comment: Also you should quote `"/usr/share/tomcat6/$(basename $entry .war)"` if you want to avoid splitting errors.

Comment: To be even safer, also quote `$entry` inside the command substitution.

Comment: @mklement0 Nice catch, completely forgot about the subshell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash wildcard globing to list only files ending in .war and then do parameter expansion with `${variable%.*}` which removes the shortest matching suffix (i.e. removes everything from the last period on and returns what's left)

```
for entry in /root/tmp/despligue/webapps/*.war; do [[ -f $entry && -d "${entry%.*}" ]] && rm -rf "${entry%.*}"; done
```

Note, the above also checks:

- That `$entry` is a regular file (not a symlink or dir); and
- That `${entry%.*}` is a valid directory before trying to remove it.

Comment: Thank's it's true, with my problems with English language, my question was bad argumented.